# Genshi: curly brace inside complex expression causes ParseError

Tags: python, genshi

I have the following Genshi HTML template snippet that is being used to generate HTML.

```
<div>
    ${'Hello {name}'.format(name='foo')}
</div>
```

Genshi throws a fit over this due to the curly braces in the string.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\genshi\input.py", line 161, in _generate
    self.expat.Parse(data, False)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 137, column 34
```

Is there a way to escape the curly braces?  Is there something better I should be using than the `${...code...}` syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're doing something more complex (code/function), you could do:

```
<div>
    Hello ${name}  // or just Hello $name
</div>
```

For something complex, use the [code block syntax](https://pythonhosted.org/Genshi/templates.html#id1):

```
<div>
  <?python
      def greeting(name):
          return 'Hello {name}'.format(name=name) ?>
  ${greeting('foo')}
</div>
```